# ImageMagick lambda layer aws SAM

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, imagemagick, aws-sam

I have the following `template.yaml` from a SAM application

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  image-resizing-lambda-js

  Sample SAM Template for image-resizing-lambda-js

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
    MemorySize: 1536

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs10.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: post
  imagemagicklambdalayer:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Application
  Properties:
    Location:
      ApplicationId: arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:145266761615:applications/image-magick-lambda-layer
      SemanticVersion: 1.0.0

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

With the following code.

Now I have read that I need to do the following to use ImageMagick with node on aws lambda is the following

Install the custom layer [https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:145266761615:applications~image-magick-lambda-layer](https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:145266761615:applications%7Eimage-magick-lambda-layer)
Link any lambda function using ImageMagick with that custom layer

It is the link any lambda function using ImageMagick with the custom layer I am confused. Do I need to do something different in my app.js code that points the imagemagick call in my code to the layer somehow. I am not entirely sure what a layer is. But my understanding is it is needed for ImageMagick to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
const axios = require("axios");
// const url = 'http://checkip.amazonaws.com/';
//const sharp = require("sharp");
const gm = require("gm");

const imageMagick = gm.subClass({ imageMagick: true });

let response;

/**
 *
 * Event doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format
 * @param {Object} event - API Gateway Lambda Proxy Input Format
 *
 * Context doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html
 * @param {Object} context
 *
 * Return doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html
 * @returns {Object} object - API Gateway Lambda Proxy Output Format
 *
 */
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    // const ret = await axios(url);
    const parsedBody = JSON.parse(event.body);
    response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: parsedBody.imagePath,
        // location: ret.data.trim()
      }),
    };

    const WEB_WIDTH_MAX = 420;
    const WEB_Q_MAX = 85;

    const url = "https://miro.medium.com/max/512/1*V395S0MUwmZo8dX2aezpMg.png";

    const data = imageMagick(url)
      .resize(WEB_WIDTH_MAX)
      .quality(WEB_Q_MAX)
      // .gravity('Center')
      .strip()
      // .crop(WEB_WIDTH_MAX, WEB_HEIGHT_MAX)
      .toBuffer("png", (err, buffer) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("An error occurred while saving IM to buffer: ", err);
          return false; /* stop the remaining sequence and prevent sending an empty or invalid buffer to AWS */
        } else {
          console.log("buffer", buffer);
        }
      });

    // gmToBuffer(data).then(console.log);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return err;
  }

  return response;
};
```

Currently I get the following error when running sam build

```
Plugin 'ServerlessAppPlugin' raised an exception: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Before addign the `imagemagicklamdalayer` section I was able to run sam build and have imagemagick run with the following error under `sam local start-api` after hitting the endpoint

```
An error occurred while saving IM to buffer:  Error: Stream yields empty buffer
```

I have got it to build with the following as the layer in the template.yaml

```
Layers:
        - "arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:145266761615:applications/image-magick-lambda-layer"
```

Now I get an error on running the function like the following

```
File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.46.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/regions.py", line 230, in _endpoint_for_partition
    raise NoRegionError()
botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.
```

Not sure where I am to specifiy this region

UPDATE:

Ok two things one I set the region in my aws config file and I set the arn to the deployed layer. I have gotten the following with something that hasn't built yet in about 5 minutes so we shall see if it ever does.

It tries to build the layer when the function is invoked

```
Invoking app.lambdaHandler (nodejs12.x)
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:396621406187:layer:image-magick:1 is already cached. Skipping download
Image was not found.
Building image...................................................................
```

UPDATE:

so it seemed to finally build but the module for ImageMagick could not be found. I have seen other examples use this layer and are calling imagemagick from a module called `gm` which is what I am doing in my code.

Does including this layer not give access to `gm` module so i can use imageMagick.

```
{"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'gm'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/app.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'gm'","Require stack:","- /var/task/app.js","- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js","- /var/runtime/index.js","    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
```

Comment: Please do not post "Update" sections to questions - just edit the whole question to be "updated" to help us understand the problem in one reading.

Comment: are you still having issues? you seem to have made progress, could you please rewrite the question to show the status as it is now? the question seems convoluted as it is right now.